# DBmails are not working after modifying the sp_send_dbmail procedure

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016

I have modified sp_send_dbmail procedure in sql server. Laster mails stopped working.
Dbmail is shutting down automatically and getting this error while I restart process

```
1) Exception Information  ===================  Exception Type: Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SqlIMail.Server.Common.BaseException  Message: The Transaction not longer valid.  Data: System.Collections.ListDictionaryInternal  TargetSite: Void ValidateConnectionAndTransaction()  HelpLink: NULL  Source: DatabaseMailEngine  HResult: -2146232832    StackTrace Information  ===================     at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SqlIMail.Server.DataAccess.ConnectionManager.ValidateConnectionAndTransaction()     at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SqlIMail.Server.DataAccess.ConnectionManager.RollbackTransaction()     at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SqlIMail.IMailProcess.QueueItemProcesser.GetDataFromQueue(DataAccessAdapter da, Int32 lifetimeMinimumSec)     at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SqlIMail.IMailProcess.QueueItemProcesser.ProcessQueueItems(String dbName, String dbServerName, Int32 lifetimeMinimumSec, LogLevel loggingLevel, Byte[] encryptionKey, Int32 connectionTimeout)
```

Please do help me

Comment: Please clarify what do you mean by modifying sp_send_dbmail. Preferably with code you executed

Comment: okay, let me be very clear with this. I have modified sp_send_dbmail procedure in msdb database to avoid certain attachment files to be inserted in sysmail_attachments table. Since I altered the procedures, dbmails stopped working and all the mails are going into sysmail_unsentitems. Dbmail is starting and shutting down automatocally and getting above error everytime I start dbmail manually.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like self inflicted wound. I think now you have 4 options:

1. Restart the instance and hope it will work (You haven't said you did it already)
2. Fix the procedure yourself
3. Alter the procedure to initial version and pray it will work
4. Restore msdb to time before any modifications

I don't think modifying MS provided objects is a wise move.
If you really, really want to do it, just script sp_send_dbmail out and create a separate procedure based on it.

Comment: Yeah, may be my fault. I tried first 3 options , didn't work. Unfortunately there is no backup for msdb. If I repair the server with setup.exe file, does it work?

Comment: Kind of. Check out this link: [Rebuild system databases](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/databases/rebuild-system-databases?view=sql-server-ver16). Proceed with caution. Unless someone else comes with other ideas I think that's your best option now.

Comment: I think that's the only option left as of now. can I ask one more question? If I rebuild system databases, will I lose user databases also?

Comment: @Jagapathibabu "*If I rebuild system databases, will I lose user databases also?*" - No. But you should take full backups of all the user databases before anything else gets messed up. This is something you should be routinely doing for all databases already.

Comment: Yes I'm taking daily backups, but when I tried to rebuild system databases on testing server with the given steps by MS but I lost user databases as well and server looked like complete new one. Did I miss something during rebuilding?

Comment: @Jagapathibabu You just need to reattach those databases again. You would also lose any server-level settings, logins and certificates, as well as all your Agent jobs, settings and DBMail settings. But you could just grab the code for that one procedure and `ALTER` it, without restoring all the system databases.

Comment: @Charlieface, thank you for the detailed information. Actually I have restored the old code for the procedure, but still getting same error. The Actual issue is, SQL server is not  automatically starting the DBmail.exe. Its starting and shutting down automatically. I should better take backup of all databases and rebuild the system databases.

Comment: @charlieface Thank you so much for you time to help in resolving this issue. But unfortunately those tips given by you didn't work for making DBmail work again.
I have tried some other procedure, it worked for me.
Let me share those steps here.

Comment: 1. Take full backup of all databases.
2. connect to cmd with admin privileges
3. Close all connections on msdb
4. go to admin path in cmd then run below commands
5. net stop mssqlserver
6. net start mssqlserver /t3608
7. SQLCMD -E -S. -dmaster -Q"EXEC sp_detach_db msdb"
8. go to data file in sql server path and change the msdb name
8.go install folder path in sql server path
9. open instmsdb script and copy it
10. Do not connect to server directly from ssms. click on newquery in ssms and connect to server
11. now run the copied script.
12. New msdb with dbmail is ready.

Comment: Yeah that works, to just replace that one database. Be aware it contains all of your SQL Agent jobs as well. Why not  post an answer below?